# Frame goes transparent on tap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project with a ListView and each item has a Frame with a white background. My problem is I recently noticed when I tap the Item it makes the Frame's background white. It still shows all the other objects but the frame goes transparent.

The frame is simply

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" Margin="10, 10, 10, 5" BackgroundColor="White">...</Frame>
```

Comment: im so sure its not the frame but your listview selected item

Comment: Can try  remove selected item background in native list view?

Comment: I solved this recently using effects and did a quick write-up. perhaps this will help? https://iwritecodesometimes.net/2018/02/01/xamawin-override-select-state-using-effects/

Comment: @Joe worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting above comments-answer to real-answer for readability sake:

The behavior you are seeing is specific to iOS. You can solve it by overriding the default behavior using an effect, like so:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyEffects")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(ListViewHighlightEffect), nameof(ListViewHighlightEffect))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Effects
{
    public class ListViewHighlightEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var listView = (UIKit.UITableView)Control;

            listView.AllowsSelection = false;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can apply it in your view code-behind:

```
MyListView.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve($"MyEffects.ListViewHighlightEffect"));
```

I did a short write-up on the full solution [here](https://iwritecodesometimes.net/2018/02/01/xamawin-override-select-state-using-effects/)

Alternatively, if you want to maintain the ability to select an item, one possible fix would be to add an ItemTapped handler in your code behind and null out

```
MyListView.SelectedItem = null;
```